# Как получить значение innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Есть div, который я получаю по имени класса и у которого есть строка в качестве значения `innerHTML`. Как мне получить эту строку? Если написать в консоль `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('player-track-info'));` то выводится объект у которого есть поле  `innerHTML` следующего содержания

```
innerHTML:"здесь некий код"
```

Но если ввести `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('player-track-info').innerHTML);` то в консоль выводится undefined. Что я делаю не так и как мне получить значение `innerHTML` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Там коллекция же. `getElementsByClassName`.

Бери `innerHTML` нулевого элемента, если он есть:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('player-track-info')[0].innerHTML
```

А вот рабочий пример:

```js
console.log( document.getElementsByClassName('myclass') );
console.log( document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0] );
console.log( document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0].innerHTML );
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
    <span class="someclass">какое-то содержимое</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Видать нет этого нулевого элемента, так как выдает ошибку...

Comment: Значит вопрос некорректен, ибо согласно указанным в нём данным (а именно по первому console.log) данный код обязательно будет работать

Comment: Я добавил код на фиддле, модераторы сейчас заапрувят.

Comment: @SergeySnegirev, я поправил Ваше дополнение, в движке SO фиддлы можно прямо в ответ встраивать

Comment: <div class="player-track-info">
     3 
     <span class="text_theme">/</span>
     38. Get Out Your Self 
     <span class="text_subtle">by</span> 
     <a target="_blank" href="http://www.site.ru/">Shekinah</a>
     </div>
    </div>


@Qwertiy: вот такой код в html. Его получаю document.getElementsByClassName('player-track-info');. В консоли выводится что это HTMLCollection[ ] и все.. Что это может быть? Не получается к элементам добраться.

Comment: Это наверное из-за того что я Greasemonkey  использую..